# SQL INSERT INTO syntax one field and multiple values

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, drag-and-drop

```
JS extract
----------

 document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
            // prevent default action 
            event.preventDefault();
            // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
            if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
                event.target.style.background = "#062c3c";
                dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
                event.target.appendChild(dragged);
                event.stopPropagation()
                    }
        }, false);

        function myFunction() {  
        document.getElementById("drop").addEventListener("submit", myFunction);
        }


html extract
------------


        <form action="data_ddexample2.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" form id="interiorstyle">

        <div class="draggable" id ="draggable"><name="interiorstyle" value="Scandinavian"><img alt="Scandinavian" class="draggable" draggable="true" height="200" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData" src="carda1.jpg" tabindex="1" width="200"></div>

        <div class="draggable" id ="draggable"><name="interiorstyle" value="Eclectic"><img alt="Eclectic" class="draggable" draggable="true" height="200" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData" src="carda2.jpg" tabindex="2" width="200"></div>

        <div class="draggable" id ="draggable"><name="interiorstyle" value="Industrial"><img alt="Industrial" class="draggable" draggable="true" height="200" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData" src="carda3.jpg" tabindex="3" width="200"></div>


    <div class="dropzone" input type="hidden" name ="dropzone1[]" id="dropzone1" multiple>
    <p>1<sup>st</sup> Preference</p>


PhP extract
-----------


        $dropzone1= $array["dropzone1"] = ['scandinavian', 'eclectic', 'industrial', 'vintage', 'minimalist', 'midcenturynodern', 'coastal', 'contemporary', 'traditional', 'bohemian', 'hollywoodglam', 'rustic', 'frenchcountry', 'transitional', 'none', 'other'];

        $dropzone2= $array["dropzone2"] = ['scandinavian', 'eclectic', 'industrial', 'vintage', 'minimalist', 'midcenturynodern', 'coastal', 'contemporary', 'traditional', 'bohemian', 'hollywoodglam', 'rustic', 'frenchcountry', 'transitional', 'none', 'other'];

        $comment = $_POST["comment"]; 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO task2ctest (dropzone1, dropzone2, comment)
                VALUES ('$dropzone1', '$dropzone2', '$comment')";


SQL Syntax error
----------------


        Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testsdd\data_ddexample2.php on line 95

        Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testsdd\data_ddexample2.php on line 95
        New record created successfully
```

The question
        The comment is posting fine, but only the word 'array' is posting to SQL rather than the actual div value of the array. So, to summarise, I just want to POST the value of whatever the user drags into the divs named dropzone1 and dropzone2. I am assuming this is to do with the INSERT INTO syntax, but I may have missed something in the html or JS code.

Comment: Your PHP code seems to be missing a part. Did you paste the complete example? From what you wrote, the data is submitted via post. You did not collect that data back from the $_POST object ($_POST['dropzone1']), you're instead just saving the array with all the values.

Comment: *** Also, use `implode` to convert array to string to insert in the SQL https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp... by the way, this SQL statement is not safe from SQL injection. You should look into that.

Comment: Hi , thank you for getting back to me. Yes, my PHP code is just an extract. Tried posting the rest of the code, but it is too long

Comment: Yes, I want to get one value back from 16 options, and I want to get this value back from the dropzone, which is just a div. I looked at implode, will check this again. I was expecting to be able to INSERT INTO

Comment: I think it is this part of my code that is incorrect. I got the radio buttons and dropdowns to work fine, so I think it is just this part of my code that is incorrect. $sql = "INSERT INTO task2ctest (dropzone1, dropzone2, comment)
                VALUES ('$dropzone1', '$dropzone2', '$comment')";

Comment: Use `var_dump` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to print the values of  $dropzone1 and $dropzone2,... check if it contain the values you need (or expected) on submit.

Comment: Ok , Thank you I will check out the PhP manual as well.

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to look out for SQL injection as well, just in case. I know the code you presented in your question is just a sample. Here's a link:  http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: It's for my PhD, so I am planning just to password protect the website.